# Image Map / Sprite Tool

Tags: image, sprite, css-sprites

Is there a tool that allows you to upload and maintain images as individual entities, but allows you to reference them in an image map as sprites?

Maintaining image sprites is a real pain in the butt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally use Sprite Gen ( http://spritegen.website-performance.org/ ). I usually use their auto-generated CSS, and simply regenerate it when I change an image.

One of my collegues prefers the web spite generator (http://westhoffswelt.de/projects/web-sprite-generator.html), which is a command line tool based on a config file.

Comment: Does that command line one allow you to keep the individual files on the server, and easily regenerate when you update the files? It's obviously important that the positioning of the images doesn't change when you regenerate.

Comment: No it doesn't, because the goal of the program is to achieve the maximal compression ratio. It is optimaly used in conjunction with smart disposition algorithms. However, you can set your configure file to customize the output CSS. Moreover, it's written in PHP, so you could build a custom DefinitionWriter from scratch to write (or update) your CSS.

Answer (score 5):

You should try http://gluecss.com It will do the dirty job for you creating all css/less and image file only calling one command. The +1 for using this kind of tools is that you don't depend on an external service that may be offline next time you try to rebuild your sprite.

Comment: Looks like @JorgeBastida is the author of this tool. Great work!